# data structure for sorted keys

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a stream of data with (id, data) pairs. I want to put them into a container for lookup and need to keep them sorted. I can guarantee that `id` will be strictly increasing. But `id` may not be consecutive. For example, the data may look like

```
(1001, data1)
(1005, data2)
(1013, data3)
```

My first choice in C++ is `std::map`. It satisfies all my needs for lookups and sorted keys. However, it seems the performance of `map` is not the best because each insertion needs O(log(n)) time.

I also considered `std::vector` as another choice. But the problem with `vector` is that my `id`s are not consecutive so I can't use `id` as the index of vector as it will consume a lot more unnecessary memory.

I wonder if other data structures are more suitable for this situation, that can take advantage of the already sorted data as well as achieve a fast lookup.

Comment: Insertion of already sorted items into a map is an O(1) operation (for each insert). Make sure you use the `insert` overload that takes a hint. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) particularly the section on complexity and overloads 4-6.

Comment: *I wonder if other data structures are more suitable for this situation, that can take advantage of the already sorted data as well as achieve a fast lookup.* -- *so I can't use id as the index of vector* -- But since the vector is sorted, you can use [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and `std::upper_bound` to search for the element.  The vector would probably be `std::vector<std::pair<int, data>>` and you use the id in the predicate in either lower_bound or upper_bound.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes , but it's not always less than `O(log(n))` when using map.

Comment: @AnotherHM I'm basically mentioning to the OP that a (sorted) vector *can* be used, and there is no need for the id to be used as an index if using lower_bound/upper_bound.

Comment: how about `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: @AnotherHM -- The OP stated that they want the keys ordered.

Comment: *"But the problem with `vector` is that my `id`s are not consecutive so I can't use `id` as the index of vector as it will consume a lot more unnecessary memory."* -- so don't use `id` as the index (store `id` in the vector alongside the data, as would be done in a `map`). Any other problems with `vector`?

Comment: The only reason to prefer `std::map` over a `std::vector` sorted by `id` is if you want to modify it so often that it makes a difference. If the data is (mostly) static, `std::vector` has the same lookup time complexity, uses less space, and has better memory locality (so might even be faster).

Comment: in case the "gaps" are small, why not use the vector? It would just spoil some (empty) entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, there is a nice flow chart to find out, what container could be good.

This has been shown here on SO by Mikael Persson. Please see below:

[image]

The obvious answer would be: Use a `std::map`.

But your requirements are not fully clear. So, we could come up also with different solutions.

- Use `std::map`in normal way. Adding data will be a little slow. Accessing and iteration will be reasonable fast.
- Use `std::map`s `insert`function using the `end()` iterator as a hint. This will speed up insertion a lot. Accessing and iteration will be the same as above.
- Use a `std::vector` of pairs holding the index and the data. Use `std::lower_bound` for looking up the index. Pre-reserve memory for the `std::vector`. (I do not know if this works for you). Insertion will be very fast. Data retrieval slow. Iteration would be reasonable.
- Use a `std::vector` of Data and store at the index positions, leaving gaps and wasting memory. Pre-reserve memory for the `std::vector`. That is really very fast, for reading and writing. But you have gaps in the data. So iterating over the `std::vector` will be difficult and maybe slow. And in essence, the data would not be sorted.
- Use above 2 methods with `std::vector`, but do not reserve memory upfront. Adding data will be slower, but still reasonable.

I have written a test program to get an idea of the resulting speed.

But as said. It depends on your use case.

Maybe, using the idiomatic correct solution with a `std::map` and hint would be advisable.

Please see the test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>

// Put the path of your test file in here
const std::string testFileName{ "test.txt" };

// For test purposes we use 'int' for your requested datat type. change it to what you want
using Data = int;

// We will create a test file with this number of data
constexpr std::size_t NumberOfTestData = 10'000'000;

void createTestFile() {

    if (std::ofstream testFileStream{ testFileName }; testFileStream) {
        int index{};
        Data data{};

        int delta{ 1 };

        for (std::size_t i{}; i < NumberOfTestData; ++i) {

            testFileStream << index << '\n' << data << '\n';
            index += delta; data += delta++;
            if (delta > 5) delta = 1;
        }
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n--- Error: Could not open '" << testFileName << "'\n";
    
}

struct Timer {
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> startTime{};
    long long elapsedTime{};
    void start() { startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); }
    void stop() { elapsedTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startTime).count(); }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Timer& t) { return os << t.elapsedTime << " ms "; }
};

#define CREATE_TEST_FILE 0

constexpr std::size_t IOBufSize = 5'000'000;
char ioBuf[IOBufSize];
std::array<std::pair<int, Data>, NumberOfTestData> allData{};
int main() {

#if CREATE_TEST_FILE
    Timer t1; t1.start();
    createTestFile();
    t1.stop(); std::cout << "\nDuration for test file creation: " << t1 << '\n';
#endif

    
    if (std::ifstream testFileStream{ testFileName }; testFileStream) {

        testFileStream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(ioBuf, IOBufSize);

        Timer t; t.start();

        for (auto& [index, data] : allData)
            testFileStream >> index >> data;

        t.stop(); std::cout << "\nDuration for reading test data from file: " << t << '\n';
        testFileStream.close();
        {
            // Copying data from file into map
            std::map<int, Data> dataMap{};

            t.start();
            for (auto& [index, data] : allData)
                dataMap[index] = data;

            t.stop(); std::cout << "\nDuration for adding to map without hint: " << t << '\n';

            t.start();
            unsigned long long sum{};
            for (auto& [index, data] : dataMap)
                sum += dataMap[index];
            std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << '\n';
            t.stop(); std::cout << "Duration for accessing all data: " << t << '\n';
        }
        {
            // Copying data from file into map with hint
            std::map<int, Data> dataMap{};

            t.start();
            for (auto& p : allData)
                dataMap.insert(dataMap.end(),p);
            t.stop(); std::cout << "\nDuration for adding to map with hint 1: " << t << '\n';

            t.start();
            unsigned long long sum{};
            for (const auto& [index, data] : dataMap)
                sum += dataMap[index];
            std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << '\n';
            t.stop(); std::cout << "Duration for accessing all data: " << t << '\n';
        }
        {
            // Copying data from file into vector using pairs
            std::vector<std::pair<int, Data>> dataVector{};
            dataVector.reserve(allData.size());

            t.start();
            for (auto& p : allData)
                dataVector.push_back(p);
            t.stop(); std::cout << "\nDuration for adding to vector of pairs: " << t << '\n';

            t.start();
            unsigned long long sum{};

            for (auto& p : allData)
                sum += std::lower_bound(dataVector.begin(), dataVector.end(), p.first, [](const std::pair<int, Data>& p1, int i1) { return p1.first < i1; })->second;
            
            std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << '\n';
            t.stop(); std::cout << "Duration for accessing all data using lower_bound: " << t << '\n';
        }
        {
            // Copying data from file into vector 
            std::vector<Data> dataVector{};
            dataVector.reserve(allData.size() * 6);

            t.start();
            for (auto& p : allData)
                dataVector[p.first] = p.second;
            t.stop(); std::cout << "\nDuration for adding to vector of Data: " << t << '\n';

            t.start();
            unsigned long long sum{};
            for (auto& p : allData)
                sum += dataVector[p.first];
            std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << '\n';
            t.stop(); std::cout << "Duration for accessing all data from vector via index: " << t << '\n';
        }
        {
            // Copying data from file into vector using pairs without reserve
            std::vector<std::pair<int, Data>> dataVector{};

            t.start();
            for (auto& p : allData)
                dataVector.push_back(p);
            t.stop(); std::cout << "\nDuration for adding to vector of pairs without reserving space: " << t << '\n';

            t.start();
            unsigned long long sum{};

            for (auto& p : allData)
                sum += std::lower_bound(dataVector.begin(), dataVector.end(), p.first, [](const std::pair<int, Data>& p1, int i1) { return p1.first < i1; })->second;

            std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << '\n';
            t.stop(); std::cout << "Duration for accessing all data using lower_bound: " << t << '\n';
        }
        {
            // Copying data from file into vector 
            std::vector<Data> dataVector{};

            t.start();

            int oldIndex{};
            for (auto& p : allData) {
                int i = p.first-oldIndex+1;
                while (i--)
                    dataVector.push_back({});
                oldIndex = p.first;
                dataVector[p.first] = p.second;
            }
            t.stop(); std::cout << "\nDuration for adding to vector of Data without reserving space: " << t << '\n';

            t.start();
            unsigned long long sum{};
            for (auto& p : allData)
                sum += dataVector[p.first];
            std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << '\n';
            t.stop(); std::cout << "Duration for accessing all data from vector via index: " << t << '\n';
        }

    }
    else std::cerr << "\n--- Error: Could not open '" << testFileName << "'\n";
}
```

That will result on my machine (10 years old, Windows 7) in:

[image]

Comment: *"As you know,"* -- weird way to start an answer. You're basically saying "You already know the answer". I'd avoid this phrase in any answer, especially as the first words of an answer. Just start with "There is a nice [...]".